# Django 'ListBlogPost' object has no attribute 'get_object'

Tags: python, django

here is my code. I am new in django. I am not understanding why I am getting this error **'ListBlogPost' object has no attribute 'get_object**. anyone please help:

**#views.py**

```
 class ListBlogPost(ListView,FormView):
           model = Blog
           template_name = 'blog.html'
           form_class = BlogFrom
           
           def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse('blog')
    

      
           def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
              data = super(ListBlogPost, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
              data['blog_admin_form'] = BlogFrom()
              
              return data
          
           def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            self.object = self.get_object()
            form = self.get_form()
            if form.is_valid():
                
                return self.form_valid(form)
            else:
              
                return self.form_invalid(form)
    
           def form_valid(self, form):
            form.save()
            return super(ListBlogPost, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: A `ListView` has no `get_object`, since it retrieves a *collection* of items, not a single item.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem Thanks for your commet. I am not understanding what I need to be do with this line `self.object = self.get_object()` it seems to me error occurring for this line.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  can you please show me  what I need to be do with this line `self.object = self.get_object()` I am new in django. From last three hours I am struggling for solve this problems

Comment: can you first say *what* you aim to achieve?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This is the page where I listing my all pending blog post. If I choose "publish" it will be publish otherwise not.

Comment: I would advise to make two views, one for the `ListView`, another to publish and redirect to that `ListView`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah I can create separate view for publish blog then redirect back to  list page. But I want to do it in list view. is it possible???

Comment: well you definitely need to redirect, since that is the Post/Redirect/Get pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem most probably error occurring for this line `self.object = self.get_object()`  I think something need to be do in this line for fix the error.

Comment: of course, and doing that in a `ListView` would be *ugly* design. Since then you need to attach *two* url patterns to the same view.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the error saying `'ListBlogPost' object has no attribute 'get_object.` is it redirect related issue???

Comment: no it is simply because this is a `ListView`. You thus render a list, and thus a `get_object` is non-sensical.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what is the best way to implement forms in list view? is it good practice? sometime we might be need to use forms in list view.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how to solve the problems which I am getting? what I need to be do ?

Comment: what does the form do here? If you only approve a blogpost, then I don't see what the form is doing here.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem the forms I using just approve and denay blog post. I know I can use seperate view where I can do the same things and redirect back to  list page. I just wasnt to know is it possible to use forms in list view? if yes the how to solve the problems which I am getting ?